# Run ActiveMQ Artemis on WIndows Server

Tags: activemq-artemis

Sadly I need to install ActiveMQ Artemis on a Windows Server.
I was able to create the broker and started it.

When I try to access the console, after the login page I got this screen. (Below image).

I tried to add this line on jolokia-access.xml

```
<allow-origin>*://localhost*</allow-origin>
<allow-origin>*://localhost:8161*</allow-origin>
<allow-origin>*://*0.0.0.0*</allow-origin>
<allow-origin>*://*0.0.0.0:8161*</allow-origin>
```

Didn't work.

Disabled the Windows Firewall, same behavior.

Are there more configurations that can I do to solve that?

Thanks!

[image: Artemis]

Comment: Maybe you could provide more details about how you created the instance? I have just tried 2.6.2 on a Windows Professional VM because I don't have any Windows Server. I did the following steps:

`artemis create --allow-anonymous --user admin --password admin c:\path\to\instance\dir` 

After that, when launching it, I just accepted the default firewall settings on the popup. 

That was all that was required for accessing .

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I did run the same command as you, without the path. I created into the /bin folder. I tried to create on 2 Windows Machine and works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow access from everywhere the config in jolokia-access.xml can be:

```
<allow-origin>*://*</allow-origin>
```

From a security perspective this is no best practice because you are allowing to connect from everywhere. It is a good start to have access but the config should made more restrictive later to protect Artemis.

For all details see [Jolokia Documentation: Chapter 4. Security](https://jolokia.org/reference/html/security.html)

## Appendix 1

Also check the binding in `bootstrap.xml`, e.g.:

```
<web bind="http://0.0.0.0:8161" path="web">
```

From [Artemis Documentation: Bootstrap configuration file](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/using-server.html#bootstrap-configuration-file):

> - `web` - Configures an embedded Jetty instance to serve web applications like the admin console.

## Appendix 2

As a workaround for Internet Explorer enter the following for the `Connection Settings`:

- Name: `artemis` (or whatever name you want)
- Scheme: `http` or `https` (depends on your configuration)
- Host: `localhost` (on server) or ip/servername
- Port: `8181` (depends on your configuration)
- Path: `console/jolokia` (depends on your configuration)

Click on `Connect to remote server` opens the dashboard. To see the details of the acceptors/addresses navigate to `JMX` / `org.apache.activemq.artemis`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I tried these 2 configs and got the same behavior... Now I'm working on Windows Firewall. Maybe some config is blocking the service.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem but I don't know how to solve.
The problem is on Internet Explorer.
I installed the Firefox on the server and the console works fine.
Maybe is a Security Policy on Windows Server but I didn't find a solution.

I did the above configuration that @BiNZGi said above to access the console remotely, so I don't need access the server anymore.

Thanks!

Comment: See Appendix 2 for a workaround with Internet Explorer. I would appreciate if you mark my answer as correct.